# Does the restriction functor $j^* $ to Zariski open preserve the limit of $j^*$-split cosimplicial diagram?

Tags: infinity-categories, monads

This might be a trivial question but I could not find a satisfatory answer easily.

Let $X = \mathbb{C}$ and $U = \mathbb{C}^*$, and let $j: U \to X$ denote the open embedding.

Consider $j^* : QCoh(X) \to QCoh(U)$. It is known that $j^* $ preserves finite limit, however $j^* $ does not preserve arbitrary limit.

For example,
$  \mathbb{C}[[x]]$ is the limit of
$$ \cdots \to \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^3) \to  \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2) \to  \mathbb{C}[x]/(x) $$
where I abused notation to use quasi-coherent module of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ to mean objects in $QCoh( \mathbb{C})$. But when restricted to $U$, all the terms in the diagram become zero, whereas  $ \mathbb{C}[[x]]$ survives to $ \mathbb{C}((x))$.

The question is, does $j^* $ preserve the (homotopy) limit of $j^*$-split cosimplicial diagram. You may upgrade $QCoh(X)$ to its appropriate $\infty$-categorical version. This kind of condition appears in Barr-Beck-Lurie's comonadicity theorem. But I am not sure how to check it by hand (or by any other means).